# URL to QR code generator not working with GET parameters

Tags: html, qr-code

I am trying to generate QR code from [this site](http://goqr.me/api/) . I want to generate QR codes of URLs. Its working all fine, except that when the URL contains a query line `index.php?action=someting&action2=this`, the QR code only corresponds to `index.php?action=someting`. You can check it here : https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=index.php?action=someting&action2=this

What to do to encode the entire URL

Answer (score 1):

Passing the URL from php using [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) helped.

Comment: you should mark your answer as solved. I found this Q&A through a Google search for something.